# Buy item facebook dont work(as3)

Tags: java, facebook, flash

I was trying to develop system to purchase items at Facebook using as3 (flash), but when I test the application I get the response that `"The app you are using is not responding. Please try again later.`"

I tried several examples including the Facebook Developer docs. This is the code I am using.

```
    public function buyItens(event:MouseEvent):void {
        Facebook.api('/me?access_token='+access_token);
        var order_info:Object = { 
           title:'Test buy item.',
           description:'Item test',
           price:'10',
           item_id:'1a'
        };
        var obj:Object = {
           //method: 'pay',
           action: 'buy_item',
           order_info: order_info,
           dev_purchase_params: {'oscif': true}
        };
        Facebook.ui('pay',obj,callback);
    }

    private var callback=function(data) {
            dTrace(data['order_id']);
          if (data['order_id']) {
             dTrace("callback"+data['order_id']);
            return true;
          } else {
            //handle errors here
            dTrace("callback handle errors here");
            return false;
          }
        };
```

I am a beginner Facebook developer. Other functions, such as buying credits and earning credits work, but buying items does not. What's the problem?

Comment: I found a way to load the window to purchase items at Facebook. I used an example of a page in php for the callback, at the end of this link: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/payments/callback/
Lack get the result of that callback. If I buy the item (100 coins) as the application receives this value? In this case the file. Swf on the page of the application. When the purchase is finalized is discounted credits in facebook.